# Handle wrong request type Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, routes, request, get

I am developing a Laravel application, and I have encountered problems when testing my routes. I registered a route in my *web.php*, for registering new Users:

```
Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware('guest');
```

It works fine, but if I try to access the route with get request, I get the following error:
**The GET method is not supported for route users. Supported methods: POST.**

Is it possible to return 404 page if I try to access a route, with wrong request type like this?

I have tried naming my routes with post request for names that have a route with get request, and it works, but I am wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider overriding render() method of **App\Exceptions\Handler** class like below:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return $this->shouldReturnJson($request, $e)
                ? response()->json(['message' => 'not found.'], 404)
                : abort(404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```